# How to redirect from one URL to another with Nginx reverse proxy

Tags: docker, nginx, proxy, reverse

How to redirect from one URL to another which is using Nginx as a reverse proxy?

Comment: not need Dockerfile

Comment: Nginx works great as a reverse proxy, inside or outside of Docker. However, we need to know how you are using it to be able to help you. Please provide all relevant files: Dockerfile, docker-compose.yml, nginx.conf, default.conf, etc.